# Searching in mysql table on email(unique) column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several questions in mind,

1) Is searching on int key is faster than searching on string key?

Relevance of my second question depends totally on answer of first,
If yes,

2) I have a table which have a [1-5]billion records, having a unique email column. I am planning to have one more column that will store hashcode(int) of email(string). Whenever I want a record with given email, I will search records with the hashcode of the email and then match the exact email.

How effective will be second? Please suggest if there is any better alternative available.

Comment: I do not believe that you have a table of 1 billion unique email addresses. (the world population is 7 billion)

Comment: @EdHeal Suppose, I have 1 billion unique strings

Comment: Perhaps partitioning the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CPU can compare an integer faster than a string.  Strings are represented as ASCII encoded integers in memory, so to compare a string the program must first convert and compare each character before a conclusion is returned.  In MYSQL, if you have a UNIQUE column combined with a fixed length VARCHAR, the search time will be very fast because the mysql engine will build a tree and use that to search for the key.  Without those two, the mysql engine must compare each email row to the search criteria.  MySQL has advanced through the years and there are lots of build in mechanisms that can be leveraged to make database management extremely fast.